# Can someone walk me through this java code?

Tags: java, inputstream, bufferedreader, fileoutputstream

I am having a difficult time comprehending how this java program works. I do know that we have the I/O library for the files. Here is the code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class SimpleRandomAccessFile {
       public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            RandomAccessFile inout = new RandomAccessFile("inout.dat", "rw");
            inout.setLength(0);

            for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
                    inout.writeInt(i);
            System.out.println("Current file length is " + inout.length());
            inout.seek(0);
            System.out.println("The first number is " + inout.readInt());

            inout.seek(2*4);
            System.out.println("The third number is " + inout.readInt());

            inout.seek(8*4);
            System.out.println("The ninth  number is " + inout.readInt());

            inout.writeInt(200);

            inout.seek(inout.length());
            inout.writeInt(1000);
            System.out.println("The new length is " + inout.length());

            inout.seek(9 * 4);
            System.out.println("The tenth number is " + inout.readInt());
            inout.close();
       }
}
```

Any help or feedback would be great!

Comment: SO is not for such questions

Comment: This question id appropriate for code review at the SO network.

Comment: This question is not useful to others in its current form. Please choose a specific question that you wish to have answered, and an example that displays your problem.

Answer (score 0):

An int is 4 bytes. So the first int can be read at position 0 in your file. Then 2*4 would be the first byte of your next int, so on and so forth. You could over loop n*4 where n is the integer to read. You need to be sure you're reading integers though, or you will run across undefined behavior.